# Defining submodules in vector from 1 to 5?

Tags: vector, git-submodules, omnet++

How do I define submodules in vector from 1 to 5?

Like in tic[6], it starts from 0 to 5, but I want to start it from 1 to 5. How do I do that?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Submodules in a vector always starts from 0.

Comment: So its not possible than to start from 1 to 5?

Comment: No, it is not possible to have numbers from 1 to 5, only 0 to 4.